Computing an approximate basis for $\text{span}\{u,v\}$ using the power method with a real initial vector

Suppose that the eigenvalues of a real $n\times n$ matrix $A$ satisfy $|\lambda_1|=|\lambda_2|>|\lambda_3|\ge\dots\ge|\lambda_n|$,
where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are complex conjugates.
Let $S=\text{span}\{u,v\}$ be the spanning space of two real vectors satisfying
$A(u+iv)=\lambda_1(u+iv)$.
Using the power method, how does one compute an approximate basis for $S$ with a real initial vector?

I'm new to the power method. As far as I know, the method can only compute one approximating eigenvector at a time.
Should I use 2 linearly independent vectors instead?
My intuition is that we can decompose the starting vector $x_0$ as $x_0=a(u+iv)+\bar{a}(u-iv)+x_{\perp}$, and since each $x_k$ is real, the iterates converge to a non-trivial vector in $S$. But then again, only one vector is not enough to form a basis. How do I proceed?
